# Please do not reveal spoiler block contents in newsletters or other emails

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

> *I posted the same request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326177/please-hide-meant-do-not-reveal-spoilers-in-emails) on meta, where it turned out to be an effective duplicate of [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184962/spoiler-text-is-not-hidden-in-newsletter); you may wish to support the latter. Since I was directed to [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without/306398#306398) which suggested trying to get community support, I have reproduced it here, as this is probably one of the most affected communities.*

Questions such as [Why did Narcissa Malfoy lie about Harry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/why-did-narcissa-malfoy-lie-about-harry#) are too often quoted in emails with spoilers partially revealed: the newsletter of 2019-04-01 displays the first **six words** of the **spoiler block** in that question.

It seems to me evident that it would be desirable not to reveal spoilers in emails and very likely that it would not be too hard to do, probably by simply omitting the contents of all spoiler blocks completely. Could you please do this?

If anyone feels that it *is* reasonable to reveal them in emails, I feel the burden of proof is with them: please explain why almost everybody who does not want details revealed on the site should be happy to read them in emails, or why they should be expected to deprive themselves of email notifications if they feel otherwise. If some people are just not bothered, fair enough, but perhaps they can support consideration for others anyway. If it is too hard to be worth doing, I should be interested in an explanation.

Note that there is no need to judge what a spoiler is, just accept the judgement of the poster, and the newsletter will do as good (or bad) a job as the questions themselves.

Many users will not be much affected by spoilers in the newsletters, but for some people they are very disappointing, and given that we have a spoiler function it ought to be well implemented.

Comment: We have a newsletter?

Comment: @Valorum: That is what it is called when it turns up in my inbox: “_Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange Newsletter - Monday, April 1, 2019_”; just a sampling of new, active and unanswered questions.

Comment: @Valorum https://scifi.stackexchange.com/newsletter/preview

Comment: FYI: it is perfectly acceptable to post feature requests and bug reports for the Stack on per-site metas; see [this dev response here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240571/152515) (in particular the last sentence). In short: it's best to put it on Meta Stack Exchange if it affects all sites, and best to put it on one site's per-site meta if it only or primarily affects that site. Even when it affects more than one site it's OK to post it to just one site's per-site meta; devs can still find it.

Comment: @doppelgreener - OP appears to have posted it on both Meta:SE and here. It was revealed to be a duplicate there.

Comment: @Valorum I'm aware. I also saw yesterday that they were being criticised for posting it here despite it being perfectly OK here (seems those comments are gone now), it's those comments that prompted me to leave the FYI here today.

Comment: @doppelgreener - I'm honestly at a loss what they hope to achieve by posting it here when it's already been posted to Meta SE. That also being said, the fact that the dupe post has garnered 13 votes in just under 6 years would suggest that it's not a burning issue.

Comment: @Valorum: I thought had clarified my motivation for this post in a comment answering one of yours, but those comments are gone, so I have extended the introductory paragraph to supply the information.